# Gradle unable to compile. Lib looking for unrelated drawable

Tags: gradle, compilation

Don't really know what happened but gradle stopped compiling my application:

[image]

The thumb_seekbar_worthwhileness.xml has nothing to do with the lib (android-maps-utils). I've tried to invalidate cache and restart, update lib version, update app-compat version to 28 (same as compile sdk) and nothing. I'm really stuck!

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

After hours looking for what might have gone wrong, I found a duplicate line in a drawable xml file:

[image]

I wasn't even in the referenced file. This is a really annoying situation.